# Textfield keyboardType is not working in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I made a **customTextFieldClass** and also had been added a `Modifier` for `TextField` in my app. But problem is `.keyBoardType` not working in `TextField`.

- **CustomTextField()**

```
struct CustomTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var tag:Int = 0
    var placeholder:String?
    @Binding var strText:String
    
    class MoveToNextTextField: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        @Binding var strText: String
        
        init?(strText: Binding<String>) {
            _strText = strText
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            if let nextField = textField.superview?.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
                nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            } else {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
            return false
        }
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
            guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }
            let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)
            textField.text = updatedText
            return true
        }
        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            strText = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextField>) -> UITextField {
        let tmpFeild = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        tmpFeild.tag = tag
        tmpFeild.delegate = context.coordinator
        tmpFeild.placeholder = placeholder
        return tmpFeild
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> CustomTextField.MoveToNextTextField {
        return MoveToNextTextField(strText:$strText)!
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextField>) {
        uiView.text = strText
    }    
}
```

- **MyTextFieldModifier()**

```
struct MyTextFieldModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .frame(height: 40.0).font(.custom(FONT.PoppinsRegular, size: 16)).background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).foregroundColor(Color("lightGreen")).padding(.horizontal, -10.0)).padding(.horizontal,45).accentColor(Color("ThemeGreenColor"))
    }
}
```

> - **Code**

```
     CustomTextField(tag: 1, placeholder: "Phone",strText:self.$txtPhone)
             .keyboardType(.numberPad)
             .modifier(MyTextFieldModifier())
      CustomTextField(tag: 2, placeholder: "Email",strText:self.$txtEmail)
             .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
             .modifier(MyTextFieldModifier())
```

- Images

[image: TesxtField editing begin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI standard `.keyboardType` is for SwiftUI standard `TextField`. If you use UIKit `UITextField`, you have to use corresponding UIKit `UIKeyboardType`.

So below is fixed variant (tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4) for usage

```
CustomTextField(tag: 1, placeholder: "Phone", 
    strText:self.$txtPhone, keyboardType: .phonePad)
```

[image: demo]

and code

```
struct CustomTextField: UIViewRepresentable {

    var tag:Int = 0
    var placeholder:String?
    @Binding var strText:String
    var keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default

    class MoveToNextTextField: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        @Binding var strText: String

        init?(strText: Binding<String>) {
            _strText = strText
        }

        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            if let nextField = textField.superview?.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
                nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            } else {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
            return false
        }
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
            guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }
            let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)
            textField.text = updatedText
            return true
        }
        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            strText = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextField>) -> UITextField {
        let tmpFeild = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        tmpFeild.tag = tag
        tmpFeild.delegate = context.coordinator
        tmpFeild.placeholder = placeholder
        tmpFeild.keyboardType = keyboardType
        return tmpFeild
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> CustomTextField.MoveToNextTextField {
        return MoveToNextTextField(strText:$strText)!
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextField>) {
        uiView.text = strText
    }
}
```